# What are some phrases or words to describe a person who enjoys family life and values family over other things?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, expressions

What is a phrase or word to describe a person who enjoys family life and values family over other things?

The only phrase I can think of is 'family person/people', which I think is not proper or even right. Please offer me some?

Comment: “family-oriented” (adj) or “family man” (noun, males only)

Comment: @StephenS: [True, dat!](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she+is+a+family+woman%2Che+is+a+family+man&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20is%20a%20family%20man%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Che%20is%20a%20family%20man%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/family_man) has this definition for 'family man':

> A man with a wife (or long-term partner) and children, especially one who enjoys home life.
> *‘I'm very much a family man and need to be close to those I love’*

It's very natural these days to change the gender of expressions like this, so 'family woman' or the gender-neutral 'family person' would be widely understood.